# Can't enable remote management after joining domain

Tags: amazon-web-services, winrm, windows-server-2016

I've got a windows server 2016 DC, and another server 2016 machine. By default, the second machine had remote management enabled (showed up as "Enabled" under Server Manager > Local Server).

After joining the machine to the domain, remote management has been disabled. When I try and re-enable it in Server Manager, it shows a progress bar for a few seconds and then then does nothing.

I've also tried setting the group policy key "Windows Components > Windows Remote Management (WinRM) > WinRM Service > Allow remote server management through WinRM" but that appeared to also have no effect.

In the event viewer, there is a message about failed group policy updates - possibly related.

```
The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not resolve the computer name. This could be caused by one or more of the following:
a) Name Resolution failure on the current domain controller
b) Active Directory Replication Latency (an account created on another domain controller has not replicated to the current domain controller)
```

If it matters, both computers are in the same AWS subnet, and both have a public IP address, but security group rules prevent them from receiving connections from the internet at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

If enabling through GUI fails with no error, first of all try to check its current status outside of GUI by using **Configure-SMremoting.exe -get** and then try **Configure-SMremoting.exe - enable** - if it won't work out for you it may give you some error message to work with.
See more details oh this in Microsoft documentation: [Configure Remote Management in Server Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server-docs/management/server-manager/configure-remote-management-in-server-manager)

Comment: Eventually I figured out my EC2 security group config was blocking some traffic to the domain controller, based on pure guesswork. No helpful error message at all!